# Get UICheckbox Issue in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, checkbox, unity-game-engine

I have problem with using UICheckbox in UNITY3D.The problem is **Default execute the UICheckbox method means without clicking checkbox its executes the 1 st time scene loading or Run the scene**

**I am using Total 8 UiCheckboxes so Not Single Checkbox,But here as shown below single**.

**UICheck Box:**

```
Event Receiver : Here attached Script - Settings

Function Name  : OnActivate
```

**Settings Script :**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnActivate()
    {
    Debug.Log (" Settings :: :: Clicked ");
    }
 }
```

I didn't get any idea about this.How to do OnActivate() executes when ever clicks Uichexbox only?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Which object name do you want, the script's or the checkbox's?

Comment: Checkbox name and it is checked or not?.@FunctionR

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the reference to the CheckBox.

```
UICheckbox checkbox = GameObject.Find("PressedButton").GetComponent<UICheckbox>();
```

Then you can check if it is checked.

```
if(checkbox != null && checkbox.isChecked) 
   Debug.Log("Checkbox " + checkbox.name " is checked.");
```

Comment: yes,its works but when ever run the scene its default calls any() check box method.So how to stop that?.@FunctionR

Comment: @Venkat What do you mean? I didn't understand you.

Comment: When Ever runs/Play this scene it's default calls the checkbox method without clicking checkbox also.Why?.@FunctionR

Comment: Your code makes `Function Name : Any` this call. Just remove it, it seems like you don't need it.

Comment: how i can know if it is checked or not without function name?.@FunctionR

Comment: yes,that can be check after enters in to a method.Before how i can know **PressedButton Namee**@FunctionR